# Server Provisioning with Jenkins and Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: jenkins, build-automation, provisioning, vmware-fusion

I do have an Ubuntu Server 12.04 VM using VMWare Fusion that i would like to provision with a set of Jenkins Steps.

So far i have the server VM with the following packages by default when installing the OS.

1. default-java (This is the OpenJDK for Jenkins Slave)
2. openssh-server (for communication with my clients)

I would like to make the following changes to this VM template so i can use it later for any purpose.

1. Change the hostname/hosts configuration (needs a reboot)
2. run package installations if necessary (git-core)
3. Install a puppet master server.

I do have a problem when trying to execute commands since ubuntu does not have the root account.

```
+ sudo hostname ubuntu
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I did try changing the sudoers NOPASSWD configuration for the sudo group members with luck only if i log in to the VM but not with jenkins even when the jenkins user is the only user in the system that is a member of the sudo group.

I would say having and image with a specific OS should be enough but i am guessing in this scenario need the jenkins slave in place to start managing the VM. I am not using Vagrant since is super slow on the MAC and VM Ware Fusion is super fast even than parallels.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an shell script that will act as your askpass program. It needs to output the password when executed. e.g., if your password is `mycleverpassword` then the following script will do the trick:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo mycleverpassword
```

Then, instead of calling `sudo hostname ubuntu`, you would call

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS="/path/to/myaskpass.sh"; sudo -A hostname ubuntu
```

Lemme know if pain persists.

Comment: @Maverick, did you try it?